Flutter web unable to load network images
I have a flutter web app, but I am not able to load network images from server which the url is set default to download (if I post this link in chrome, it doesn't show the image but download it), the url is:
https://chilleasy-documents.oss-cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/dev/property/319/11/4370f5db603c49d7b0d2caa7a409955a.jpg
The widget that I used to show the images is:
Image.network(MasterImageList[index].image_path, fit: BoxFit.contain)

Any ideas?

Refer  this answer for network images loading on web

are you sure it contains valid image data?

@pskink yes, is a valid image link

I know it's valid link, I mean if it contains valid image data, tried to download it and open with any image processing app?

@RavindraS.Patil it works if I type the command --web-renderer html in terminal, but in this case, I can't debug the app as it doesn't show the check points that I added

@pskink I can open the image with chrome or other image editor after it is downloaded

"I have a flutter web app, but I am not able to load network images from server " what is the Object error if you use ImageErrorWidgetBuilder? errorBuilder in Image.network constructor?
